# Changing Yaw, Pitch And Roll OpenGL

Tags: opengl, java, 3d, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL and OpenGL 1.1 at this time and I was wondering what command is used to change the yaw, pitch and roll?

Comment: check this out : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147028/are-euler-angles-the-same-with-pitch-roll-yaw

Comment: @Nicolas Brown I see stackexchange really covered all the subjects :).

Answer (score 2):

[glRotatef](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glRotatef%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

```
glRotatef(Angle.X, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ;
glRotatef(Angle.Y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) ;
glRotatef(Angle.Z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) ;
```

(which of those angles are 'yaw', 'pitch', and 'roll', and the order in which you apply them, will depend on which axis you're considering to be 'up')

Comment: -1: For using Euler angles without any mention of the pitfalls of this. Like Gimbal Lock and such.

Comment: I didn't choose to use euler angles -- the OP did.  It was explicitly a "what is the function to apply pitch/yaw/roll in this API" question, and my answer is the objectively correct answer to that question.  If I'd provided an answer which said how to rotate by a quaternion or by a rotation matrix, it would not answer the question which was asked.

Comment: With that said, it would absolutely be appropriate to provide a "here's why you may not want to do that" note as a comment on the question.  It's just not an answer to the question that was asked.